# Wake up asio deadline timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

I have the following thread pool.

```
#include <queue>
#include <map>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp> // remove me (only for io)

class ThreadPool
{
    void run() {
        // get some work from a task queue and then work on it
    }
public:
    void work_as_mainthread(void) { m_io_service.run(); }

    ThreadPool(int poolSize = 4) : timer(m_io_service)
    {
        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        m_pWork.reset( new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_io_service) );

        for ( int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i)
            m_threadGroup.create_thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_io_service) );
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_pWork;
    boost::thread_group m_threadGroup;
};

int main()
{
    int n_threads = 2;
    ThreadPool pool(n_threads);
    // add some tasks here...
    pool.work_as_mainthread();
    return 0;
}
```

It is a minimal exaple, full code [here](http://pastebin.com/jXAg2XRL). Compile like this:

```
g++ -Wall -g -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_system main.cpp -o main
```

Note that I have no async_wait() called (I don't know why I should need it, the thread pool works so far).

Now, it might happen that suddenly one task wants another task to be done before the other task's timeout. What's the best way to tell the m_io_service to execute the handler immediatelly (even if the timer is not interested yet), and then to continue as if nothing happened? I could not figure out from the sparse documentation, really.

This did not work:

```
timer.expires_at(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
```

Comment: If you don't call async_wait, then what handler are you talking about?

Comment: I just posted more code here. I hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help. Please, explain the purpose of the timer in your code. What is it expected to do? If you never call `async_wait` (or sync. `wait`), it does nothing. What handler are you talking about?

Comment: I think I get your question. Code is missing. I used the `post` method. Let me edit my post, one second!

Comment: Ahh, it works now. After calling `deadline_timer::expires_at()`, indeed, I forgot calling `deadline_timer:async_wait()`. Instead, I called `io_service::oist()`, which executed the task _immediatelly_. Thanks Igor, your hint was good, I really forgot `async_wait()`.

Comment: @Igor turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `expires_at` only sets `dealine_timer` expiration time, but doesn't "enable" the timer, so there's no asynchronous operation associated with the timer. You should call `async_wait` passing it a completion handler: when the timeout is expired or the timer is cancelled, this handler gets called in one of the associated `io_service`'s threads.

Calling `io_service::post` is unrelated to `deadline_timer`. It just posts your functor to `io_service` queue, and `io_service` invokes it as soon as it can in one of its threads.